# 2 conditions in a Powerapps filter formula

Tags: powerapps

I use some code found in MIKAEL SVENSON blog: https://www.techmikael.com/2019/01/a-no-nonsense-solution-to-implement.html.
Here is the sample code:

```
ForAll(
    Filter(
            Cities, // SharePoint list with all cities
            Country.Id = CountrySelector.Selected.Id // Pick cities where country matches the selected one
        )
    ,
    {
        Value: Title, // Create a new item with Value/Id, which will save correct
        Id: ID // It's important to have Value as the first field!
    }
)
```

How can I add another condition?

Here is my example working:

```
ForAll(
    Filter(
            'Bâtiments/Zones', 
            Site.Value = SiteSelection.Selected.Value
        )
    ,
    {
        Value: Title, 
        Id: ID 
    }
)
```

Here is what I want to do:

```
ForAll(
     Filter(
             'Bâtiments/Zones', 
             Site.Value = SiteSelection.Selected.Value && Title = ZoneSelection.Selected.Value
         )
     ,
     {
         Value: Title, 
         Id: ID 
     } )
```

I tried with & AND || with no success.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
ForAll(
    Filter(
            'Bâtiments/Zones', 
            And(Site.Value = SiteSelection.Selected.Value,Titre=ZoneSelection.Selected.Value)
        )
    ,
    {
        Value: Local, 
        Id: ID 
    }
)
```

Comment: You might want to edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it helps.